# Why it doesn't generate me first n prime numbers?

Tags: c++

Can u give me some help?I'm beginner and I dont know what's wrong with my program.It generates me all numbers to n not just prime numbers. why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int i,n,d;
    bool prim;
    cout<<"n=";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i=i+1)
    {
        prim=true;
        for(d=2;d<=i/2;d=d+1)
        if(i%d==0)
        {
            prim=false;
            break;
        }
        (prim);
        cout<<i<<",";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can code with correct indent in  spaces and braces. It always help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `(prim);` use `if(prim)`. The rest of your code is correct.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 unsigned int i,n,d;
 bool prim;
 cout<<"n=";
 cin>>n;
 for(i=2;i<=n;i=i+1)
    {
     prim=true;
     for(d=2;d<=i/2;d=d+1)
     if(i%d==0)
     {
         prim=false;
         break;
     }
     if(prim)
         cout<<i<<", ";
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `(prim)` is not the same as:

```
if (prim) {
    cout << i << ",";
}
```

On a side note:

- `d=d+1` and `i=i+1` can just be `d++` and `i++`
- You can declare variables inside the loops like: `for (int i = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for printing is not correct.

```
    (prim);cout<<i<<",";
```

should be

```
    if(prim) cout<<i<<",";
```

Note that your logic prints primes <= n, not the first `n` prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You missed off the `if`:

```
if (prim) cout << i << ',';
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement could be reduced a little bit:

```
prim && cout<<i<<",";
```

This is because of the shortcut evaluation of logical expressions. So `cout` will only be evaluated if prime is true. If it is false, `cout` will be not evaluated as the expression is false anyway.

Minor comment: The divisor (d) may be increased till floor(sqr(i)), not till i/2 (more effective). Variable i may be started from 3 and increased by 2 as all even numbers are not prime (except 2, it can be printed without counting...).